# Difficulty archiving static library in Xcode (not found)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am having difficulty creating an ad hoc archive of my project, as it includes another Xcode project that builds a static library. When I'm building for development, everything works fine. However, when building for ad hoc or release, I have the following problem in the main Xcode project:

```
'DHxls/DHWorkBook.h' file not found
```

What is different about building for release than building for development? Do you know what is causing this issue?

[image]

Comment: Look at the "Header Search Paths" under Build Settings. Most likely you have a different value between Debug and Release.

Comment: @rmaddy There are none for either. Perhaps this is an issue with archiving, versus just building to run in the simulator? What do you think?

Comment: It works for me but my setup may be slightly different? What is your configuration choice (release? debug? custom?) when you go to edit scheme >> archive? Also, try adding DHxls to build phases > target dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I found this Apple Developer doc very helpful.  Bottom line for me was archiving doesn't execute the copy public headers build phase.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html

Comment: dead link . . . .